# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, scapy

I can't import the module "scapy" in my virtual environment.
I tried it with python 3.6.9 (which i have to use for my project) and python 3.7. None of them versions did work.

Import variants like

```py
from scapy.all import *
```

or

```py
import scapy
```

or

```py
from scapy import IP, sr1, ICMP
```

all these did not work.

None of the other posts I found solved my problem.

The installation via `pip` in the virtual env was successful. After that the module appears in the results of

`pip list`

I let printed out the paths, which python searches for modules and found, that the path to the scapy module wasn't in it, which is kinda interesting because isn't that the usual way one would expect using virtual envs...?! Anyway, after adding this path:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/username/Desktop/environments/my_env/bin/')
```

it also didn't work, even though the scapy binary is located in the same bin folder as python.

I already tried to reinstall ... basically everything.

Comment: Is the `python` you are using to call the script the same one that's running `pip`?

Comment: Since i work in a virtual environment, which i set up with a specific python version (3.6.9), Yes.

Comment: Wait, *the scapy binary is located in the same bin folder as python*. What do you mean by this? Python will search the `site_packages` folder located at `/path/to/env/lib/python3.6/site_packages`. Can you verify the output of `python -m pip list` and that the library is located? Sometimes the bare `pip` executable can be pointing to many different places

Comment: I work in a virt environment, installed scapy in there and checked where scapy is located as follows:

`which scapy`

The result: 

`/home/username/Desktop/environments/my_env/bin/scapy`

The python executable is also located in the bin folder.

Therefore i checked the output of 

`import os
print(os.sys.path)`

output: 


`['', '/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/username/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
`

Comment: Obviously the path where scapy is located is not in there, but that doesn't make sense for me since I installed it within the virtual environment.

Comment: It's obviously not a Scapy bug but an issue with your setup. You should probably rephrase your issue a bit

Comment: The scapy executable is not what you're looking for. It doesn't look like the output from `sys.path` includes your virtual environment. Did you activate the environment?

Comment: Also always use `python[3] -m pip [...]` instead of `pip`

Comment: @C.Nivs Yes, i did activate it.

Comment: @Cukic0d Whats the difference between python3 -m pip and pip? I wouldn't expect any difference in a virtual environment configured with python3.

Comment: I have "solved" the problem by setting up a new virtual machine which is very unsatisfactory. Probably an issue with different python installations/reinstallations.

Comment: @Cukic0d Btw I tried out both variants (python3 -m pip install scapy vs. pip install scapy), each in a new clean virtual environment and both worked.

Comment: We're at the point where we have basically no idea of what your setup is, facing one of the most common python-related issues ever. I'm just throwing in general advices: `python -m pip` makes sure you're using the same Python install to install and run the program

Answer (score 0):

did you install scrapy by accident? (scrapy instead of scapy)?

Comment: No 100% sure its scapy. It works when i start it from the command line, but i want to use it in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Well it did happened with me as well, and guess what I had  a script saved as "scapy.py!
That was the problem in my case! Lesson learned :) be carefully when you choose a name for your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem with python3.8 . I am a Kali Linux user and I was working on a project. In that project I needed to import 'scapy' module. So, normally I installed scapy with pip. But it didn't run with python3.8 . Then I noticed that, I could run the same python script with scapy module with python 2.7. Then I just simply got on a terminal and put these simple commands...

```
sudo cp -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scapy /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/
```

By this command I copied the scapy module from python 2.7's directory to python 3.8's directory.

If this doesn't work then follow this command also...

```
sudo cp -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/
```

This solution worked for me. Hope this will work for you as well.
Thanks.

Comment: In python 3.9, `pip install scapy` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

These are different ways to fix this issue:

**1.** Don't Use IDLE

IDLE can cause issues with scapy, and even if it works, you may get a OSError. Use another better text editor like VS.

**2.** Use The Right Command

Scapy is one of those modules that requires work to install, for some people, simple commands like this will not work:

```
pip install scapy

pip3 install scapy
```

Try these commands instead that have worked for me to install and use scapy. I have provided 4 commands you should use on a command line interface to make sure that at least one works. Try them one by one. They work in my experience.

```
py -m pip install scapy

py -3.12 -m pip install scapy

pip install scapy==2.5.0

pip3 install scapy==2.5.0
```

The py command is used like the python command. It was introduced with Python 3.3 and it is a Python launcher. The python command is more general though.

If these did not work, please go [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy), file a issue and click [here](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) to read how to download and install. It includes other ways like installing the development version or using Git to install it.

Comment: What is py command? Is that an alias?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, it is a alias. However, the python command is more general. It allows you to run different versions of Python installed to your system too.